# Ruby - How to create a class variables to access in function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a function to set the instance variable like `attr_reader`

```
class Base
    def exec
       # get all functions to check
       # if all functions return true
       # I will do something here
    end
end
```

And then I have a class inherit `Base`.

```
class SomeClass < Base
  check :check_1
  check :check_2

  def check_1
   # checking
  end

  def check_2
   # checking
  end
end

class Some2Class < Base
  check :check_3
  check :check_4
  
  def check_3
   # checking
  end

  def check_4
   # checking
  end
end
```

Because I only need 1 logic for executing in all classes but I have a lot the different checks for each class, I need to do it flexibly.

Please, give me a keyword for it.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have `check :check_1` you need to define `check` as a *class method*:

```
class Base
  def self.check(name)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Since you want to call the passed method names later on, I'd store them in an array: (provided by another class method `checks`)

```
class Base
  def self.checks
    @checks ||= []
  end

  def self.check(name)
    checks << name
  end
end
```

This already gives you:

```
SomeClass.checks
#=> [:check_1, :check_2]

Some2Class.checks
#=> [:check_3, :check_4]
```

Now you can traverse this array from within `exec` and invoke each method via [`send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Object.html#send-method). You can use [`all?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Array.html#all-3F-method) to check whether all of them return a truthy result:

```
class Base
  # ...

  def exec
    if self.class.checks.all? { |name| send(name) }
      # do something
    end
  end
end

SomeClass.new.exec # doesn't do anything yet
```

The `self.class` part is needed because you are calling the *class* method `checks` from the *instance* method `exec`.

Comment: tks @stefan.

I found what I want.

I used `class_variables` for this

Comment: @tai.groddy note that a class variable (with `@@`) is shared between the class and its subclasses. You probably want to have a _class instance variable_ (with `@` as shown above) so each subclass can have its own array.